# Selecting style attribute with REGEX in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking to get *only* the style attribute and it's contents using regex in php.

For example

**Input**
`<img src="test.png" style="float:left;"/>`

**Desired Output**
`style="float:left;"`

---

**What i've tried:**

This seems to return the entire image, and i'm not sure why.  I suck at regex.

```
$img = '<img src="test.png" style="float:left;"/>';
preg_match('/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i', $img, $match);
```

Returns:

```
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => <img src="test.png" style="float:left;"
        [1] => <img src="test.png"
    )
```

Anyone with any pointers?

Cheers.

Comment: `style` attribute? Please see [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/112968) on why RegEx is not always the right tool for the job.

Comment: Yeah I understand that, but in this situation i _have_ to use regex unfortunately.

Comment: Can you use javascript string operators?

Comment: @Greg: Why can't you _not_ use RegEx? I'm really interested in the reason.

Comment: @Knittl I'm working with some messy code I've inherited and don't have the time to adapt the rest of the code to use XML parsing

Comment: You don't have to adapt the rest (although it would be good). If the rest works as is, leave it alone.

Comment: Yeah I suppose you're right. I'll look into it, cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have it almost correct, you just need to capture the part you want, by surrounding it in parenthesis. You're currently capturing the wrong part:

```
$img = '<img src="test.png" style="float:left;"/>';
preg_match('/<[^>]+ (style=".*?")/i', $img, $match);
$result = $match[1];
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/PU56PG)

Note: This will work for simple inputs like the example `<img>` tag, but for anything more complex Regex is not powerful enough to parse HTML, since HTML is not a regular language. If you find that it's not powerful enough you can use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), which is meant for this sort of thing.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!  
It's literally as simple as my example, so Regex works fine for now.  If I had the choice I'd definitely use DOMDocument parsing.  Thanks again!